# Automate login to a website

Tags: java, sockets, web

I want to make an application which logs into a web site by filling form, perform basic operations such as button click etc and finally log out. What package / external jars are available for this?

Comment: tcp/ip ? did you google your question ? there are thousands of examples, for instance: http://www.coderanch.com/t/524061/open-source/Java-program-Login-website-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at java.net.URL, java.net.HttpURLConnection, and java.net.Authenticator.

Comment: How will i fill the write on the form y using theese?

Comment: @dpanshu All that question tells me is that you haven't looked at them yet.

Comment: I have now, I asked these questions almost an year ago. I apologize for the mess.

Comment: I have learnt to use the documentation and the API's thanks to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to open an HTTP connection, 
get the form (using GET method), 
and fill in the details, and POST probably perform a POST of the login data. 
Bare in mind that most sites  provide some security, such as SSL , or other mechanism, you will have to deal with this in your application (the same way browser knows how to handle this).